# What is wrong with the following code in vivado hls?

Tags: vivado, vivado-hls

The following code should read a value from DDR, decrement it, write the result back to the same address, and read the next value, repeating 256 times.

Instead on the first run it decrements the first 2 values (axi_ddr[0] and [1]), and on consecutive runs it only decrements the first value (axi_ddr[0]).

```
#include "ap_cint.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "string.h"

void hls_test(volatile int256 axi_ddr[256], uint32 *axi_lite_status_control){
    #pragma HLS INTERFACE s_axilite port=axi_lite_status_control register bundle=BUS_A
    #pragma HLS INTERFACE s_axilite port=return bundle=BUS_A
    #pragma HLS INTERFACE m_axi depth=256 port=axi_ddr bundle=DDR

    int256 axi_ddr_reg;
    int256 diff = 1;
    uint9 i = 0;

    if (*axi_lite_status_control == 1){
            for(i = 0; i < 256; i++){
                axi_ddr_reg = axi_ddr[i];
                axi_ddr[i] = axi_ddr_reg -diff;
            }
            *axi_lite_status_control = 2;
        }
}
```

Both simulation and cosimulation passes as intended, and cannot figure out what is causing the issue.

Also tried C++, but it ended in the same behavior. The only time it was different, was when I forgot to give initial value to variable diff, and then the value in all 256 DDR locations became 0x0.

Could somebody please point out what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine to me and it should work flowlessly. However, if you're saying that both simulation and cosimulation pass, then something might be wrong with either you test code or with your hardware implementation.
Also, for the C++ version of the code, you shall be using the `ap_uint<N>` types defined in `ap_int.h`, instead of `ap_cint.h`.